# Use Arabic URL structure in nuxt project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a BIG and important question. What will happen if I changed my language to Arabic language?

example:

I have the following stracture

`my-website/pages/listing/index.vue`

I navigate to this page by using the following url `http://localhost:3000/listings`

but because of the SEO perspective, I want to change the language like this `http://localhost:3000/معالم`

so I have to rename the folder name like this `my-website/pages/معالم/index.vue`

But I get the following error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in vue-router and nuxt. In vue-router it was [fixed](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/pull/2375), but not released. Once a new release of vue router will be available, this [PR](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/3841) in nuxt will be merged and it should work.

Comment: @AbdallahSabriHussein you could only wait when a new version of vue router & nuxt will be released. Another option is to fork vue router and nuxt and apply that changes and use your copies of libs, but thats not a viable approach